# Complex query for hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I have three tables with entities in hibernate. DB - MySQL. I need to get fields from entity "Item" where ModelsMm.id has some value. At first I tried to do separate queries, it was huge amount of requests in sum. So, i tried to do complex query, but it became a very long run.

I think there is a simpler way, but I do not know what.

My query and entities.

```
    List<Item> itemIds = session.createQuery("select it from Item it where :id in elements(it.mmPrice.modelsMm)");

    @Entity (name = "MODELS_MM")
    public class ModelsMm {

        @Id
        private int Id;

        @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name="parth_mm", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MODEL_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PART_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
        private List<MmPrice> mmPrices;

    @Entity (name = "MM_PRICE")
    public class MmPrice {

        @Id
        private int id;

        private String article;

        @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "article", referencedColumnName = "article",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Item item;
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="parth_mm", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PART_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MODEL_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
        private List<ModelsMm> modelsMm; 

    @Entity
    @Table(name="SHOP_ITEMS")
    public class Item implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private int id;
        private String article;

        @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "article", referencedColumnName = "article",insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private MmPrice mmPrice;
```

In console i have that query

```
Hibernate: select item0_.ID as ID0_, item0_.ARTICLE as ARTICLE0_, item0_.article as article0_ from SHOP_ITEMS item0_ cross join MM_PRICE mmprice1_ where item0_.article=mmprice1_.article and (? in (select modelsmm2_.MODEL_ID from parth_mm modelsmm2_ where mmprice1_.ID=modelsmm2_.PART_ID))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to fix your mapping. In a bidirectional association, one side MUST be the inverse side, and thus use the mappedBy attribute. For example, if you choose ModelsMm to be the inverse side, then its mmPrices attribute should be declared as

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modelsMm")
    private List<MmPrice> mmPrices;
```

You should also forget about CascadeType.ALL on ManyToMany associations: it makes no sense. You don't want to delete all the courses of a student when you delete a student, since the course is also followed by several other students.

Now, regarding your query, it's not very clear what you want to do. If you want to select all the items which have a price which have at least one model whose ID is in a collection of IDs, then you simply need the following query:

```
select distinct i from Item i
join i.mmPrice p
join p.modelsMm m
where m.id in :modelIds
```

Side note: please fix your naming. This inconsistent and unnecessary usage of `mm` as a prefix or suffix makes the code unreadable. Name your class `Price`, the fields of type Price `price`, and the collections of prices `prices`. Just as you would do in English: an Item has a price, and a price has models.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i didn't fully understand about inverse mapping. If I do mapping like you said, what will be in entity "MmPrice"? With your query program get an error "Unexpected token:". It's about p.modelsMm. I'm using secondary table "parth_mm" for mapping modelMm and priceMm. This table is given to me from the outside.

Comment: The MmPrice won't be changed at all. Regarding the error: paste the complete and exact error message.

Comment: `[ERROR] hql.PARSER line 1:124: unexpected token: :
unexpected token: : near line 1, column 124 [select distinct i from hobbystart_database.ru.hobbystart.hibernate.Item i join i.mmPrice p join p.modelsMm m where m.id in :modelIds]`

Comment: It worked after i changed "in" to "=". Time for requesting changed from 30 sec to 20 sec, where 130 modelIds and each have 125-300 mmPrices

Comment: That's still too much time. Use explain to see what takes so much time, and add appropriate indices